# Design pattern for handling different sets of inherited variables?

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I have a base class that stores all columns of a record of a database. I want to have three child classes that send different fields of that record to different recepients using the Run() method.

But, here is the problem that child classes inherit variables (fields of the databse record in this example) that are not used.

I only want to use common fields in the base class, and store the others in child classes.

Then how would I set the member variables of child classes using the base class pointer?

None of the classes `Child1`, `Child2`, `Child3` use all the fields (`field1`, `field2`, ...). If transfer the fields that each child wants into its own class, then I how would I use SetFields from parent to set different fields in different child classes?

```
class Interface
{
public:
    int field1, field2, field3, ..., fieldN;
    void SetFields(field1,field2,field3,fieldN); // --\> gets all the fields as arguments
    virtual void Run() = 0;
};

class Child1 : public Interface
{
public:
    void Run() {
    /// send field1, field2, field3 to recepient1
    }
};

class Child2: public Interface
{
public:
    void Run() {
    /// send field4, field5, field6 to recepient2
    }
};

class Child3: public Interface
{
public:
    void Run() {
    /// send field7, field8, fieldN to recepient3
    }
};
```

I need a design pattern that can send child members using parent class.

Comment: Have you thought about making `SetFields` `virtual` too?

Comment: Plain (pure virtual) interfaces shouldn't contain data members. Abstract classes may support these using a _Mixin Pattern_ for implementation. Also have a look at CRTP regarding the latter. Finally check the _LOKI_ library for implementation examples.

Comment: Inheritance is not intended for variables, inheritance is related to class behavior : see [Liskov's Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  What you could do however is make an interface class with a list of pure virtual public getter functions, that is actually quite common (and very useful in unit testing). This interface would not have a Run() method that would be on another interface

Comment: Please try to indent your code to make it more readable. Your teachers, books or tutorials should have mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

**Requirements**

> I only want to use common fields in the base class, and store the
> others in child classes.

1. A class has to store common fields. -> suggested class name `Common` instead of `Interface`

> None of the classes Child1, Child2, Child3 use all the fields (field1,
> field2, ...).

2. Further classes store fields that are not common. -> suggested class name `Additional<n>` instead of `Child<n>`

> I want to have three child classes that send different fields of that
> record to different recepients using the Run() method.

3. The additional classes (`Additional<n>`) send the specialised fields.

**Design**

If I understand the requirements correctly then I do not see the need of inheritence, interface classes, base classes and such.

I suggest to use aggregation instead.

**C++ code**

```
class Common
{
public:
    int mnField1;
    int mnField2;
    ...
    AdditionalA madditionalA;
    AdditionalB madditionalB;
    ...
    void SetFields(int nFieldC1, int nFieldC2, int nFieldA1, int nFieldB1) {
        mnField1 = nFieldC1;
        mnField2 = nFieldC2;
        ...
        madditionalA.mnField1 = nFieldA1;
        madditionalB.mnField1 = nFieldB1;
        ...
    }
    void Run() {
        // send mnField1, mnField2 ...
        madditionalA.Run();
        madditionalB.Run();
    }
};

class AdditionalA
{
public:
    int mnField1;
    ...
    void Run() {
        // send mnField1
    }
};

class AdditionalB
{
public:
    int mnField1;
    ...
    void Run() {
        // send mnField1
    }
};

...
```

**Hints**

- "Contains" -> *Aggregation*

  - e.g. A record *contains* fields.
- "Is" -> *Derivation*

  - e.g. A bill *is* a document.
- "Is related" -> *Association*

  - e.g. Customer *addresses* item.